# I want to display 3 images in a row in bootstrap using ruby loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display 3 images in a single row. Each image having thumbnail class. Column width is .col-xs-2. I can have the last row just having one/two/three images depending upon total images(say 7). I want to have a ruby while/for loop which will automate this and do it.

eg. x|x|x
    x|x|x
    x|
here x represent the images which are of thumbnail class. Inside col-xs-2 class.

Comment: first create a static content to display single image, then loop it dynamically using any loop like .each

Comment: I have the static page for it. But I am having problem when I am making it dynamically using the loop

Comment: You should tell that problem

Comment: I am not able to make the ruby loop to implement this static content

Comment: <% 3.times %> static image code <% end %> -- if you put your static content with in this loop it should make it three times. if it works, dynamically pass the image names to finish

Answer (score 4):

> I want to display 3 images in a single row

You need [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/Enumerable#each_slice-instance_method). This will divide your images in equal numbers. You can do

```
- @images.each_slice(3).each do |group|
  // @images is an array of images 
  - group.each do |image|
    // image is a single image in your array of 3 images
    .image-container
      = image_tag(image.url, class: "col-xs-2")
```